# Joining many tables together using key from first table for all joins?

Tags: sql, left-join, multiple-tables

I would like to do something like this but can't get it to work:

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.* FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN
B ON A.ID = B.ID
C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

I.e. I need to use a field from the first table for all joins as `tableB` and `tableC` don't
has any fields to link them together.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a join !

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.* FROM tableA A 
LEFT JOIN
B ON A.ID = B.ID
left join
C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work.
I had missed to type in tableC between JOIN and ON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tableA A 
LEFT JOIN dbo.B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.C ON A.ID = C.ID
```